# BeautifulSoup targeting label and its input attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract the text for the items where `label class="checkbox"` AND `input data-filter-name="topics"`.

The end result should print out the 13 topics located here:
https://www.pythondiscord.com/resources/

Topics should be:

- Data Science
- Databases
- Discord Bots
- Game Development
- General
- Microcontrollers
- Software Design
- Testing
- Tooling
- User Interface
- Web Development
- Other

I've gotten this far, but am unsure how I can combine the label and input into `soup.find_all()` so as to target only the 13 above. The input I'm targeting below doesn't have text to output so I am pretty sure I need some conditional formatting and or a function to accomplish this.

```
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

topics = soup.find_all('input', {"data-filter-name": "topics"})

for i in range(0, len(topics)):
    print(topics[i].text)
```

And here is a screenshot of the HTML in quetion:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing that, but you should probably try using css selectors:

```
targets = soup.select('label.checkbox input[data-filter-name="topics"]')
for target in targets:
    print(target['data-filter-item'])
```

Output:

```
algorithms-and-data-structures
data-science
databases
discord-bots
game-development
general
microcontrollers
software-design
testing
tooling
user-interface
web-development
other
```